# Application still showing in Background Processes

Tags: windows, vb.net, multithreading

I wrote a vb.net app that runs in the system tray and you show the UI by right-clicking on the icon. When you first run it, it shows up in the Apps section of the Task Manager. However after it's been running for a while, and only for some users, the app will disappear from the system tray but still appears under Background Processes in the Task Manager.

When it's in this state it's not actually doing anything and I have to force quit it. I know this can happen if a program quits or crashes but still has active threads. The application isn't quitting though. My application spawns threads for different processes and has one main thread that runs a loop in the background. But all my threads have IsBackground set to true, which should prevent that.

Any idea what would cause this?

Comment: How are you starting up your app?  Are you calling `Application.Run` in a `Main` method and passing an `ApplicationContext`

Comment: You'll first have to figure out how to get your app in this state.  Then you can attach a debugger and see what threads are still running, Debug > Windows > Threads window.  Ending an app that uses threads gracefully is never not a problem, deadlock is always a likely mishap.  If you still see the main thread back then you also have a good reason to search the solution for Application.DoEvents().

Comment: I don't have a Main function, I just have a startup form.

Comment: I've never been able to reproduce it. But I see it popping up with random clients all the time.